# Kotlin delegate object mapping

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to create a map into a kotlin class like this:

```
class RegisterThingPostBody(inputBody: Map<String, Any>) {
  val device: Device by inputBody
  val thing: Thing by inputBody

  class Device(inputBody: Map<String, Any>) {
    val serialnumber: String by inputBody
    val securityCode : String by inputBody
  }

  class Thing(inputBody: Map<String, Any>) {
    val name: String by inputBody
    val location: Location by inputBody

    class Location(inputBody: Map<String, Any>) {
        val street: String by inputBody
        val city: String by inputBody
        val state: String by inputBody
        val lat: Double by inputBody
        val lon: Double by inputBody
    }
  }
}
```

But I do get a `ClassCastException` for the objects (Thing, Device Location), which is understandable. 
I can solve it by doing as i do below, but it's not as neat as the top one. And I have to repeat the variable name twice.

```
class RegisterThingPostBody(inputBody: Map<String, Any>) {
  val device = Device(inputBody["device"] as Map<String, Any>)
  val thing = Thing(inputBody["thing"] as Map<String, Any>)

  class Device(inputBody: Map<String, Any>) {
    val serialnumber: String by inputBody
    val securityCode : String by inputBody
  }

  class Thing(inputBody: Map<String, Any>) {
    val name: String by inputBody
    val location = Location(inputBody["location"] as Map<String, Any>)

    class Location(inputBody: Map<String, Any>) {
        val street: String by inputBody
        val city: String by inputBody
        val state: String by inputBody
        val lat: Double by inputBody
        val lon: Double by inputBody
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a nice way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is untested (as you didn't provide a complete example with sample `inputBody`) and makes some assumptions about the constructors:

```
import kotlin.reflect.*
import kotlin.reflect.jvm.*

class CreatorMapWrap<T: Any>(val map: Map<String, Any>) {
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>) = property.returnType.jvmErasure.constructors.first().call(map[property.name] as Map<String, Any>) as T
}


class RegisterThingPostBody(inputBody: Map<String, Any>) {
  val device: Device by CreatorMapWrap(inputBody)
  val thing: Thing by CreatorMapWrap(inputBody)

  class Device(inputBody: Map<String, Any>) {
    val serialnumber: String by inputBody
    val securityCode : String by inputBody
  }

  class Thing(inputBody: Map<String, Any>) {
    val name: String by inputBody
    val location: Location by CreatorMapWrap(inputBody)

    class Location(inputBody: Map<String, Any>) {
        val street: String by inputBody
        val city: String by inputBody
        val state: String by inputBody
        val lat: Double by inputBody
        val lon: Double by inputBody
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I like this, one change I did was to bring `kClass` in the constructor of `CreatorMapWrap`, like this: `class ObjectMap<T: Any>(val map: Map<String, Any>, val kClass: KClass<T>)`. Then the definition looks like this: `val device by ObjectMap(inputBody, Device::class)`, But its almost the same.. Thanks!